# Error message display when trying to display 8000 records or more in datatable

Tags: datatable

Error message display like below when trying to display 8000 records or more in datatable

```
DataTables warning: table id=tblHl7 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

How can I solve this issue by able to increase display records up to 100,000 records?